# Chat Bubble background Xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, drawable

I am trying create chat drawable background but not for chat just for view.Tried using some codes no able acheive fully as per the required. please help me to finish this.

Required image:

[image]

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="100%"
        android:toDegrees="0" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

<item android:left="20dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="10%"
            android:toDegrees="0">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorBlack" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item

        android:top="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks View is good  but try to add background for layout .View not coming properly should use some other layout.

Comment: You can use this lib. https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/BubbleLayout